# Android: How to programmatically select a group of Views and modify it?

Tags: android, android-layout

My requirement is to apply '6' different colors to '6' ImageViews on programatically. In my Layout i can have more than six ImageViews and these colors has to be applied only to those specific ImageViews.

```
for (int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) { }
```

But how do i identify those specific 6 ImageViews among all the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark specific ImageViews with setTag() function (eg. imageView.setTag("Specific")) on their initialization and after that do next

```
for(i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++){
    //check for view is ImageView
    if(view.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageView){
        //check for tag
        if(((String) view.getChildAt(i).getTag()) == "Specific"){
            //code for set color
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I had thought about this solution but this statement from Developer.Android made me wonder is it the right practice to identify a view

_Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure._

Comment: @user2991413 if you are creating views programmatically, yes you can assign id programmatically too, but in this case you make be sure to avoid id conflicts. in case of tags, if you are not using them, you can add special mark to view ("store data related to views") and then check for this tag. And you are dont identifying views, you are checking is the image view suitable for your needs